# HL7 CCD: shouldn't displayName in <entry> match the name inside the narrative block?

Tags: hl7

I am looking at the sample CCD document supplied by HL7 in the CCD implementation guide.

Excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
<title>Results</title>
<text>
   <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr><th>&#160;</th><th>March 23, 2000</th><th>April 06, 2000</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr><td colspan="3"><content styleCode="BoldItalics">Hematology</content></td></tr>
         <tr><td>HGB (M 13-18 g/dl; F 12-16 g/dl)</td><td>13.2</td><td>&#160;</td></tr>
         <tr><td>WBC (4.3-10.8 10+3/ul)</td><td>6.7</td><td>&#160;</td></tr>
         ...
      </tbody>
   </table>
</text>
<entry typeCode="DRIV">
   <organizer classCode="BATTERY" moodCode="EVN">
      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.32"/> <!-- Result organizer template -->
      <id root="7d5a02b0-67a4-11db-bd13-0800200c9a66"/>
      <code code="43789009" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="CBC WO DIFFERENTIAL"/>
      <component>
         ...
      </component>
      <component>
         ...
      </component>
   </organizer>
</entry>
...
</xml>
```

As you can see, this is from the lab results section. The narrative block has a test battery (group) named **Hematology**, but it appears that the corresponding `<entry>` has a displayname of **CBC WO DIFFERENTIAL**.

Why are they different, and shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a requirement that the table in `<text>` must follow the exact same order as the coded value in the `<entry>` below. Meaning that the `<text>` provides HGB+WBC (and maybe more left out via "...") and the `<entry>` would provide some number of `<component>`s that make up the results.